# set variable in docker compose command line and read the value in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have docker-compose.yml file.

```
service:
    container_name: 'api'
    build: .
    command: export __TEST__=1 && /start.sh"
...
```

I connect to docker container and read the __TEST__ value. But value is empty, it is suppose to
be 1?

```
docker exec -it service /bin/bash

root@577cc808d888:/code# echo $__TEST__
root@577cc808d888:/code#
```

Comment: To set an environment variable for a container, we normally use the [`environment` directive in a compose file (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment).

Comment: Actually, what I want is that after all the commands are run, __TEST__=1 will be and I will understand that all the commands are working and I will do other operations.

Comment: The proper way would be to add this logic to a script file, and execute that script file as entrypoint of the container.

Answer (score 0):

When you exec into a container with a command like `/bin/bash` the command specified in the compose yaml is ignored and `/bin/bash` is executed. It's similar to how CMD works in a Dockerfile. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command).

If you want to test the variable is being set you can probably modify your command to echo the variable as well or echo it at the start of your `start.sh` script.